# Provide directions on an Android Google-Maps activity

Tags: android, google-maps

is it possible to provide directions on a map on Android from 1 place (e.g a specific lat/lng) to another  specific lat/lng? I realise this is doable with the Google-maps API but can you do it within Androids native implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I realise this is doable with the Google-maps API but can you do it within Androids native implementation?

Directions are not part of the Google Maps add-on for Android. There may be independent services you can use to obtain that information, though. Please be sure to follow their terms of service.

Answer (score 0):

I have posted my answer here. I have done this between 2 lat and lon... when click on any market from a specific lat/lon(say current location)
Please see my answer.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10994923/543022